# Related to Angular 6 onclick button and web service calling

Tags: angular

In angular 6 onclick of button it should redirect to another component and web service of that particular component should be called. How to implement this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried anything so far? Please add the details of what you've tried.

Comment: Angular has excellent documentation. Look at: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to another component, you need to implement [routing](https://angular.io/guide/router).

Your button can then use the `routerLink` directive to navigate to the second component.

When the second component loads, you can use its `ngOnInit` (or similar) [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) to call a web service.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback.  Please consider upvoting & accepting my answer.  Thank you.